# Interactive Grid - database constraint error handling for interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm working with APEX 19.2. I'm trying to handle constraint errors with an error handling function.

I have an interactive grid built on a table with unique constraint. I created `constraint_lookup` that matches constraint name with message.

I created a function mainly based on Oracle Doc example (that is for example in package wwv_flow_error_api)

The only thing I changed was the display location:

```
l_result.display_location := case
                                 when l_result.display_location =
                                      apex_error.c_on_error_page then
                                  apex_error.c_inline_with_field_and_notif
                                 else
                                  l_result.display_location
                               end;
```

Right now when I'm trying to add a value with non-unique value I get a message in notification like I wanted, but I don't know how to handle it to show error in notification and with the field (like in apex validation, where you can associate item)

I tried to list all apex_error attributes and I get

> p_error
>   message ORA-00001: naruszono więzy unikatowe (#CONSTAINT_NAME#)
>   additional_info
>   ORA-00001: naruszono więzy  unikatowe (#CONSTAINT_NAME#)
>   display_location          ON_ERROR_PAGE
>   association_type
>   page_item_name
>   region_id
>   column_alias
>   row_num
>   model_instance_id
>   model_record_id
>   apex_error_code
>   original_message
>   original_additional_info
>   ora_sqlcode               -1
>   ora_sqlerrm ORA-00001: naruszono więzy unikatowe (#CONSTAINT_NAME#)
>   error_backtrace
>   error_statement           "ADM"
>
> l_result
>   message           #ERROR MESSAGE#
>   additional_info   ORA-00001: naruszono wiezy unikatowe (#CONSTAINT_NAME#)
>   display_location  INLINE_WITH_FIELD_AND_NOTIFICATION
>   page_item_name
>   column_alias

How to connect field from constraint with the field in interactive grid?

Answer (score 0):

You should add p_page_item_name parameter. For example:

```
    p_message  => 'Employee name cannot be null',
    p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_with_field_and_notif ,
    p_page_item_name => 'P10_NAME');
```

Comment: it's not item its field in interactive grid

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your error handling function with the following code please. It adds additional debug statements.

```
if p_error.ora_sqlcode in (-1, -2091, -2290, -2291, -2292) then
    l_constraint_name := apex_error.extract_constraint_name (
                             p_error => p_error );
    apex_debug.info( 'Raised constraint error: %s', l_constraint_name );

    begin
        select message
          into l_result.message
          from constraint_lookup
         where constraint_name = l_constraint_name;
        apex_debug.info( 'Constraint found, new message: %s', l_result.message );
    exception when no_data_found then
        apex_debug.info( 'Constraint not found in constraint_lookup' );
    end;
end if;
```

Run your application in debug mode and reproduce the error. After that you can use **View Debug** to find out if your constraint_lookup entry is actually used.

Comment: But i know which of my constraint_lookup entry is used. I have uq constraint in DB and i handle the error message with error handling function, but I need to associate it with field in interactive grid like in apex validations